# app crashes due to deallocating a view

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview

hi friends i am developing a app where there many templates.swipe towards left navigates to thr next template and towards right navigates to the previous template.I have a method which gets called as soon as i swipe towards any direction which clears all the views related to the previous template and some other functionality.

i have a view "bodyBgView" which gets added for all templates except one templates(wordSearch template).the same is released every time i swipe (in the method that is called when the swipe id done) . when i swipe after visiting the template(wordSearch template) the app is getting crashed.
when i placed debugger i could see the debugging gets terminated at the release statement i.e [bodyBgView release];

the method is mandatory with the release statement b'coz all other templates depend on the method.how can i overcome the situation to get all the templates work fine.

to be precise releasing a view which is already deallocated should not abort my application.

plz help me
Tnx in advance

Comment: "releasing a view which is already deallocated should not abort my application"....Well efrank, you have to write new programming language for that..

Comment: i hope my case is a common for many and i believe that there would  a property or solution to overcome it.It may be even silly after knowing it.I hope in programming there is nothing impossible

Comment: I am not good at it, and I havent tried it too..But read about exception handling in ios sdk and see if there is any method for that..

Comment: But still I think you can find some logic which checks whether the thing is already deallocated before you call release on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my issue by assigning nil after the view is released.

```
[bodyBgView release];
bodyBgView=nil;
```

then my app was not chrashing. validation on a nil returns nil thus the app doesn't get chrashed.

hope helps others who faces same issue.

thank you